# reading from ifstream file gives wrong size

Tags: c++, vector, stl, ifstream

I have a .txt file containing 6291456 numbers and nothing else. After reading all out and `push_back` into a vector, the `vector.size()` function returns 6291457. Where does this additional element come from?

```
    int disparity;
    ifstream disparity_txt;
    disparity_txt.open(path);
    while(!disparity_txt.eof())
    {
        disparity_txt >> disparity;
        vec_disparities.push_back(disparity);
    }
    cout << vec_disparities.size() << endl;
    disparity_txt.close();
```

Comment: ...and don't use `endl` unless you *really* want a buffer flush (at a ~10:1 speed loss) along with writing a new-line character.

Comment: If the stream by error contained non-numerical data, like ordinary text, you would get an infinite loop. Eventually crashing when exhausting memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `while(!disparity_txt.eof())` [it does not do what you think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) (`eof` will only be set after the end of the stream is read, so typically the last iteration is wrong) :

Do :

```
while(disparity_txt >> disparity)
{
    vec_disparities.push_back(disparity);
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but got 3145728, half the exact size returned.

Comment: @user3921720 see my edit for the complete loop, you are doing a `disparity_txt >> disparity;` too much in the `while`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using `while (!in.eof())` is **almost always wrong**

Either stop looping when extracting a number from the stream fails (as shown in quantdev's answer) or use the standard library facilities meant for populating a container from a stream:

```
std::ifstream disparity_txt(path);
vec_disparities.assign(std::istream_iterator<int>(disparity_txt),
                       std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

You can open an fstream using its constructor, and the destructor will close it, you don't need explicit `open` and `close` calls.

In C++11 it's even simpler:

```
vec_disparities.assign(std::istream_iterator<int>{std::ifstream{path}}, {});
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting alternatives (I personally prefer the C++03 solution, I find it more readable)

Comment: quantdev's answer is better because it actually explains the problem, mine just offers an alternative solution